# Executable compiled with MinGW outputs nothing when using vector

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw

I'm new to using MinGW and C++ in general, and whenever try compile my source file, the executable seemingly does nothing, even though it should output a simple "Hello World!". I've tried commenting out the lines that use `vector`, and it'd output "Hello World!" just fine.

Source code which doesn't seem to do or output anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef long long ll;

using namespace std;

const int LIMIT = 1000000; // one million

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int* arr = new int[LIMIT] {0};
    vector<int>* v = new vector<int>();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

Source code with `vector` commented out that outputs "Hello World!" just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef long long ll;

using namespace std;

const int LIMIT = 1000000; // one million

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int* arr = new int[LIMIT] {0};
    // vector<int>* v = new vector<int>();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    // delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

Both are compiled and run with:

```
C:\Users\User\my\directory\src> g++ source.cpp -o source.exe -std=c++11
C:\Users\User\my\directory\src> ./source.exe
```

Compiling and running either doesn't produce any error message. Note that `#include <vector>` remains uncommented in both instances.

Comment: It outputs fine in both cases.

Comment: [Could not reproduce](https://ideone.com/50Dy89)

Comment: Is it possible that there may be something wrong with my MinGW setup?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but why would want use a `std::vector<T>*` at all? And Why would one not use `std::array`, when building with `-std=c++11`?